# php - how display data on the same page?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a html form that is located on contact.php , this is the Code

```
<?php  

header('Content-Type: text/html; Charset=utf-8');

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>Prove</title>

</head>
<body>

  <form  action="test.php" method="post" name="post">

        <label for="email">E-Mail</label>

                 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />

                  <label for="name">Name</label>

                  <input id="name" name="name" />

      <br>

        <label> Message: <br><textarea cols="45" rows="6"  name="message"></textarea><br></label>

     <p>

        <button  type="submit" name="post"  value="POST COMMENT">POST  COMMENT</button>

     </p>

     <br>

  </form>

    <h2>Comments:</h2>

</body>

</html>
```

The form is processed from test.php

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<?php
include "contact.php";
if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||
  empty($_POST['email']) ||
  empty($_POST['message'])) {

   echo "<br><b><h3>*** Please enter all required fields ***</h3></b>";
}
else
{
  $name = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  $datetime = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

   echo "<br>"

      . "<b>From: </b>" . htmlspecialchars( $name     )
      . "<b> at: </b>" . htmlspecialchars( $datetime)
      . "<br><br>" . htmlspecialchars( $message  )
      . "<br><hr>";
}  

?>

</body>
</html>
```

When a user fills out the form and submit it , it display on test.php instead of contact.php...

Why have two code instead all in one , for security...

My question is, how can I keep the data inside the contact.php ?

Comment: You can use ajax for example

Comment: there are the possibility only to do with php ? my knowledge mit php is very low , but  my knowledge mit ajax is nothing....

Comment: `<form  action="test.php"` submits your form to `test.php`. Change that to `contact.php` and add your logic there.

Comment: @kerbholz  , i making this but without result..

Comment: I don't understand. What is your problem exactly? Are the posted values not posted correctly to your desired page? Are you unable to fetch the values using `$_POST`? Depending on where / how you want to display your values, you can just do `echo $_POST['your_post_variable'];`. Make sure that your form action `action="test.php"` is the correct page that you wish to `POST` to. The comments are a bit cryptic as well, but is your issue that you need to infact post the variables to 2 individual pages at once? If you need to post it to 2 individual pages at the same time, I would recommend AJAX.

Comment: Might as well learn AJAX. Just because you don't know something, it doesn't mean you shouldn't try it. You should broaden your knowledge and develop yourself, always. Don't be discouraged from a challenge by learning something new. AJAX makes a lot of sense if you wish to handle your POST values and send them to multiple pages at once, but I don't really see why you would have to send your values to 2 different pages in the first place?

Comment: @Martin , thanks for yours help ! , i will not to send my POST to multiple pages , i will only to send to contact.php

Comment: about your question , how can i used $_POST as value ? i will to come only to my contact.php as i have here https://i.imgur.com/MYNTIVg.png

Comment: @3edf1w Like you already have in your test.php. Example: `$_POST['name']` is how you fetch your post variable called *name*. Whatever you want to do with that value is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so , "I" found the solution , people help me , very Thanks to they !

My **contact.php** File;

```
<?php

 include 'Classtest.php';
 header('Content-Type: text/html; Charset=utf-8');
 mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
 error_reporting(-1);

$ProveContackt=new Classtest();
?> 


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en_mx">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

 <form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="index4.php" >

<?php

 $ProveContackt->form();

 $ProveContackt->PostOk();

?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My **test.php** Code;

```
<?php

 header('Content-Type: text/html; Charset=utf-8');
 mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
 error_reporting(-1);

class Classtest {
  private $Name;
  private $Email;
  private $Message;

 function __construct() {
    $this->Name="";
    $this->Email="";
    $this->Message="";
 }

 function Form() {
     echo('<table>');
         echo('<label for="name">Name </label>');
         echo('<input type="text" name="Name" value="'.$this->Name.'">');
         echo('<label for="email"> Email </label>');
         echo('<input type="email" value="'.$this->Email.'" name="Email" ');
      echo('<tr>');
        echo('<td>');
          echo('<br>');
          echo('<label> Message: <br><textarea cols="45" rows="6"   name="Message">'.$this->Message.'</textarea></label>');
          echo('<br><br>');
          echo('<input  type="submit" name="post" value="POST COMMENT" id="comment">');
        echo('</td>');
      echo('</tr>');
   echo('</table>');
}


function PostOk() {

 $file = "test.txt"; 

 $this->Name=$_POST["Name"];
 $this->Email=$_POST["Email"];
 $this->Message=$_POST["Message"]; 

 if(empty($_POST['Name']) || empty($_POST['Email']) || empty($_POST['Message'])) {

   echo "<br>" . "<b>" . "<h3>*** Please enter all required fields ***</h3>" . "</b>";    

 } 

 else 
 {

   $name = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'Name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $datetime = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());



   $data = array("name" => $name, "email" => $email, "message" => $message, "datetime" => $datetime);


   $data = serialize($data);
   file_put_contents($file, $data . "\n", FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);    
 }   
  $messages = file($file);

 foreach ($messages as $value) {
   $data = unserialize($value);

      echo "<br>"
        . "<b>From: </b>" . htmlspecialchars( $data["name"])
        . "<b> at: </b>" . htmlspecialchars( $data["datetime"])
        . "<br><br>" . htmlspecialchars( $data["message"])
        . "<br><hr>";
   }   


 }

}



?>
```

My screeshot how to show now [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8ff9.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
header('Content-Type: text/html; Charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');
if(isset($_REQUEST['post'])){
if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||
  empty($_POST['email']) ||
  empty($_POST['message'])) {
   echo "<br><b><h3>*** Please enter all required fields ***</h3></b>";
}
else
{
  $name = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $datetime = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
   echo "<br>"
      . "<b>From: </b>" . htmlspecialchars( $name     )
      . "<b> at: </b>" . htmlspecialchars( $datetime)
      . "<br><br>" . htmlspecialchars( $message  )
      . "<br><hr>";
}  
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Prove</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form  action="" method="post" name="post">
        <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" />
      <br>
        <label> Message: <br><textarea cols="45" rows="6"  name="message"></textarea><br></label>
     <p>
        <button  type="submit" name="post"  value="POST COMMENT">POST  COMMENT</button>
     </p>
     <br>
  </form>
  <h2>Comments:</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! , but i will have two Code ,  my contact.php web site i will public to do , but test.php by security , i will to hide it ...